# Connect already existing GKE Cluster to Mongo Atlas (VPC Peering)

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, mongodb-atlas, vpc-peering

I'm trying to connect an already existing GKE cluster to a Mongo Cluster in mongo atlas.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/connect-atlas-cloud-kubernetes-peering/), with the only difference that I didn't create the GKE cluster after creating the peering, but the other way around: I created the GKE Cluster, and then, when I saw I needed the peering, I peered the VPC in which the GKE Cluster was deployed, to mongo.

Then I tried the following

`kubectl run -i --tty mongo-test --image=mongo --restart=Never -- sh`

and then `mongosh <<myconnectionurl>>`, but it fails with a timeout.

I fear the peering needs to be done BEFORE creating the GKE cluster, which would be extremely undesirable for me. Note that VPC-native traffic routing is enabled in said GKE Clustter.

Comment: 1)Check the Firewall was blocking access to port 27017.  2) Try doing this:- MongoDB Atlas -> NetworkAccess -> Edit -> Allow Any.  3) Check this [VPC Peering Between MongoDB Atlas and Google Cloud](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/vpc-peering-between-mongodb-atlas-google-cloud-eec89a261b75) for more info, the above actions may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy,  Do Mongo Atlas have a firewall? if so, how do I check it? Network  Access section doesn't have an Edit option/button... 
I'm checking the tutorial you created

Comment: Tutorial helps to resolve your issue?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I think the limitation I'm facing is the fact that VPC Peering is not supported for applications hosted in GCP, and mongo atlas clusters hosted in AWS (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-vpc-peering/#set-up-a-network-peering-connection)

Comment: Try this tutorial [Connect a GKE Cluster with MongoDB Atlas through Cloud NAT](https://dchaykin.medium.com/connect-a-gke-cluster-with-mongodb-atlas-through-cloud-nat-b0ffb2683b7d).

Comment: can you please share the complete error details?